# Testing Sinatra Applications inside Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I've created a simple application to assist me in learning Rails.

Because I like a challenge, I've also started to build, inside this application, a Sinatra app (to handle API calls without the overhead of the full Rails stack).

I've come to the point where I want to start testing both applications before I move any further, but I'm not sure where to write the tests for my Sinatra app. It's presently located under lib/api - should I create a tests folder underneath that, or use the main Rails test folder at the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this sinatra app in request of rspec by example or by integration test.

In this part you just need define which url you want request and see the result.

Comment: So, to clarify, I'd test my models in the usual way, but only integration testing the Sinatra URIs? The other part of my question was where to write these tests? In the main RAILS_ROOT/test folder, or one underneath RAILS_ROOT/lib/api?

Comment: in your test directory, it's like your sinatra app is a kind of controller.

Comment: Thanks Shingara, didn't realise you'd responded again. I've accepted your answer.